# How to display an image in real-time using Rust?

Tags: user-interface, rust, egui

I am trying to write a ray tracer and want to render my image in real time in a GUI window. Basically, I have a buffer: `Vec<u8>` that is constantly updating. The question is how do I display it on the screen after completing each row. I was thinking about using [iced](https://docs.rs/iced/latest/iced/) or [egui](https://docs.rs/egui/latest/egui/), but couldn't figure out how to output changing image without copying it each time. Solutions that are using other toolkits are also welcome.

egui asks for TextureId:

```
ui.image(my_texture_id, [640.0, 480.0]);
```

but doesn't say where to get it

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem (and I also writing a ray tracer). I am using egui, how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For egui there's [some example here](https://github.com/emilk/egui/blob/c69fe941afdea5ef6f3f84ed063554500b6262e8/eframe/examples/image.rs) and a [note here](https://github.com/emilk/egui#how-do-i-render-3d-stuff-in-an-egui-area) if you want to go 3D (with an [example too](https://github.com/emilk/egui/blob/c69fe941afdea5ef6f3f84ed063554500b6262e8/egui_glium/examples/native_texture.rs)).

For iced there's a bunch of [examples](https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/tree/master/examples), and some of them are using image/image_viewer (e.g. [pokedex](https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/blob/master/examples/pokedex/src/main.rs)).

A way to go would be to copy their code, make it compile/run, and then tweak it with your logic. If something goes wrong - you'd have more input for a more concrete SO question.

Also I don't think that there's anything wrong per se in copying the data for the purpose of buffering ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering)).

Comment: Please flesh out this answer with snippets of code relevant to the question. Links are nice but they can rot (and some did); the answer should be useful on its own.